# A link to automatically create a question tagged with something

Tags: support

We have an internal StackExchange instance and I have a question around it. Please let me know if this is not the right forum to be asking this.

The "Ask a question" link is something like "https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask" however I want to send something in the url that automatically populates the "tags" section. So something like "https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tag=horse" and the Ask question screen already has the tag "horse". I have set up my RSS/emails to monitor/track questions on the "horse" component.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yep, this feature exists:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?title=horse&tags=duck+cow
```

gives:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?title=horse&tags=duck+cow

Works for me. I think there's a parameter for the body as well, but I can't remember it